GitLab deploy fails on Docker
I'm using GitLab documentation and trying to run a standard configuration (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#pre-configure-docker-container). After running docker compose initializing is stuck on this log below, so Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails.
The container consumes 100% CPU and a lot of memory (1.3G/2G).
After accessing instance in browser there GitLab error that configuration is longer than normally (502).
Is container hanging or is it really a long configuration being set up?
UPDATE:
After a fresh try seems it proceed next after 10mins and there are new logs, but still receives 502 when entering web page and in logs there is
{"correlation_id":"","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2024-07-28T22:04:53Z","uri":""}
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:16.7.9-ce.0
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: '<removed>'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
        external_url '<removed>'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '512m'


      - change group from '' to 'root'
    * link[/opt/gitlab/init/postgres-exporter] action create[2024-07-28T21:11:17+00:00] INFO: link[/opt/gitlab/init/postgres-exporter] created

      - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/init/postgres-exporter to /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv
    * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
[2024-07-28T21:11:17+00:00] INFO: template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/run] sending run action to ruby_block[restart_service] (delayed)
    * ruby_block[restart_service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
[2024-07-28T21:11:17+00:00] INFO: template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/config] sending create action to ruby_block[reload_log_service] (delayed)
    * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action create
      * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/main] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/config] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_postgres-exporter] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * link[/var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter/config] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/env] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for postgres-exporter service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/control] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/init/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
      * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgres-exporter] action create[2024-07-28T21:11:18+00:00] INFO: link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgres-exporter] created

        - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/service/postgres-exporter to /opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter
      * ruby_block[wait for postgres-exporter service socket] action run[2024-07-28T21:11:19+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[wait for postgres-exporter service socket] called

        - execute the ruby block wait for postgres-exporter service socket
      * file[/var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter/current] action touch (skipped due to only_if)
[2024-07-28T21:11:21+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[reload_log_service] called
      - execute the ruby block reload_log_service
[2024-07-28T21:11:21+00:00] INFO: template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/run] sending run action to ruby_block[restart_log_service] (delayed)
    * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action run
      * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/main] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/config] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_postgres-exporter] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * link[/var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter/config] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/log/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/env] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for postgres-exporter service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/control] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/init/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
      * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/postgres-exporter/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[wait for postgres-exporter service socket] action run (skipped due to not_if)
      * file[/var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter/current] action touch (skipped due to only_if)
[2024-07-28T21:11:22+00:00] INFO: ruby_block[restart_log_service] called
      - execute the ruby block restart_log_service
    * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)
    * link[/opt/gitlab/service/postgres-exporter] action create (up to date)
    * ruby_block[wait for postgres-exporter service socket] action run (skipped due to not_if)
    * file[/var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter/current] action touch (skipped due to only_if)
  
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml] action create (up to date)
  * consul_service[postgres-exporter] action delete
    * file[/var/opt/gitlab/consul/config.d/postgres-exporter-service.json] action delete (up to date)
     (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::database_reindexing_disable
  * crond_job[database-reindexing] action delete
    * file[/var/opt/gitlab/crond/database-reindexing] action delete (up to date)
     (up to date)
[2024-07-28T21:11:23+00:00] INFO: templatesymlink[Create a gitlab.yml and create a symlink to Rails root] sending run action to execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] (delayed)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] 

Log after starting container 2nd time:
{"correlation_id":"01J3XKA5FG0WNCZ5XJTE0Q8GJE","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory","level":"error","method":"GET","msg":"","time":"2024-07-28T21:17:58Z","uri":"/"}
{"content_type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","correlation_id":"01J3XKA5FG0WNCZ5XJTE0Q8GJE","duration_ms":0,"host":"**<removed>**.net","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:0","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","route":"","status":502,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-28T21:17:58Z","ttfb_ms":0,"uri":"/","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36","written_bytes":3027}



check permissions on the volume mounts; 2) login into the container and see if the expected services are running; 3) are there memory settings that GitLab recommend?

